# Visualising a Python dictionary which has a different length of list of strings as values

Tags: python

Could anyone suggest what steps I should take to plot a graph or heatmap or any proper visualisation technique? Basically, I want to view the dictionary in the form of a diagram using any plotting library of Python. The diagram would display which accuracy was obtained from which numbered trial. My dictionary looks like this:

**Some background context:**

At first, I preprocessed a dataset. Train and test split was performed. Then I made two separate lists, one named scores (which is initially empty) and the other classifiers (which has a list of `KNeighborsClassifier`s with different values of `n_neighbors` and different metric distances). Then I appended the scores list like this:

```
scores = []
for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
    clf.fit(x_train_res, y_train_res)
    score = clf.score(X_test, Y_test)
    scores.append(score)
```

Afterwards, I created said dictionary like this:

```
duplicate_dict = {}
for name, score in zip (names, scores):
  #score = round(score, 4)
  score = str(score)
  if score not in duplicate_dict:
    duplicate_dict[score] = []
  duplicate_dict[score].append(name)
```

Dictionary, when printed, looks this:

```
{'0.9885185185185185': ['Nearest_Neighbors_6',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_7',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_13',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_14',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_27',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_28'],
 '0.9890740740740741': ['Nearest_Neighbors_21', 'Nearest_Neighbors_35'],
 '0.9894444444444445': ['Nearest_Neighbors_20', 'Nearest_Neighbors_34'],
 '0.9903703703703703': ['Nearest_Neighbors_5',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_12',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_26'],
 '0.9922222222222222': ['Nearest_Neighbors_19', 'Nearest_Neighbors_33'],
 '0.9929629629629629': ['Nearest_Neighbors_4',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_11',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_25'],
 '0.9931481481481481': ['Nearest_Neighbors_18', 'Nearest_Neighbors_32'],
 '0.9938888888888889': ['Nearest_Neighbors_3',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_10',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_17',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_24',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_31'],
 '0.9955555555555555': ['Nearest_Neighbors_2',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_9',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_23'],
 '0.9957407407407407': ['Nearest_Neighbors_16', 'Nearest_Neighbors_30'],
 '0.997037037037037': ['Nearest_Neighbors',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_8',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_15',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_22',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_29']}
```

Image:

[Image description: Accuracy scores are keys and values are numbered trials of running KNeighborsClassifier with different parameters despite some trials achieving the same accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHNjp.png)

Comment: added dictionary items as text too

Comment: This question seems too broad. Can you please ask more specific question?

Comment: I understand that the question is confusing. I want to view the dictionary in the form of a diagram, using any plotting library of Python such as matplotlib

Comment: And what do you want to see on this diagram? What information should it display?

Comment: The diagram would display accuracy obtained for which numbered trial

Comment: Also elaborate in your question, where this data came from, the code or the function that produced this data. This will enable us to understand your question better

Comment: Added some background info

Comment: "I want to view the dictionary in the form of a diagram, using any plotting library of Python such as matplotlib" Then… do that? I mean what exactly are you *asking* from us here? What *specific* problem do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is way too undercomplex to do any fancy visualization, you could just output the neighbors and scores in a crosstable. You can do this in the console and don't need any matplotlib:

```
d = {'0.9885185185185185': ['Nearest_Neighbors_6',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_7',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_13',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_14',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_27',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_28'],
 '0.9890740740740741': ['Nearest_Neighbors_21', 'Nearest_Neighbors_35'],
 '0.9894444444444445': ['Nearest_Neighbors_20', 'Nearest_Neighbors_34'],
 '0.9903703703703703': ['Nearest_Neighbors_5',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_12',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_26'],
 '0.9922222222222222': ['Nearest_Neighbors_19', 'Nearest_Neighbors_33'],
 '0.9929629629629629': ['Nearest_Neighbors_4',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_11',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_25'],
 '0.9931481481481481': ['Nearest_Neighbors_18', 'Nearest_Neighbors_32'],
 '0.9938888888888889': ['Nearest_Neighbors_3',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_10',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_17',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_24',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_31'],
 '0.9955555555555555': ['Nearest_Neighbors_2',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_9',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_23'],
 '0.9957407407407407': ['Nearest_Neighbors_16', 'Nearest_Neighbors_30'],
 '0.997037037037037': ['Nearest_Neighbors',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_8',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_15',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_22',
  'Nearest_Neighbors_29']}


cols = {}
for e in d.values():
    for n in e:
        try:
            num = int(n.replace("Nearest_Neighbors_",""))
        except:
            num = 1
        if not num in cols.values():
            cols[n]="{0:02}".format(num)

ncol = len(cols.values())
chunks = []
c = []
for i in range(ncol):
    if len(c)<10:
        c.append(i)
    else:
        chunks.append(c)
        c=[i]
chunks.append(c)

for c in chunks:
    print("\n"+" "*20,end="")
    for col in c:print(sorted(cols.values())[col],end="  ")
    print("")

    for case in d.keys():
        print("{0:<18}".format(case),end="")
        for col in c:
            present=False
            for n in d[case]:
                if cols[n] == sorted(cols.values())[col]:present=True
            if present:
                print("   X",end="")
            else:
                print("   0",end="")
        print("")
```

The result is then:

```
                    01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  
0.9885185185185185   0   0   0   0   0   X   X   0   0   0
0.9890740740740741   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9894444444444445   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9903703703703703   0   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0
0.9922222222222222   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9929629629629629   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9931481481481481   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9938888888888889   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   X
0.9955555555555555   0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   0
0.9957407407407407   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.997037037037037    X   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   0   0

                    11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  
0.9885185185185185   0   0   X   X   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9890740740740741   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9894444444444445   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   X
0.9903703703703703   0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9922222222222222   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   0
0.9929629629629629   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9931481481481481   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   0   0
0.9938888888888889   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   0   0   0
0.9955555555555555   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9957407407407407   0   0   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0
0.997037037037037    0   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0

                    21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  
0.9885185185185185   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   X   0   0
0.9890740740740741   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9894444444444445   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9903703703703703   0   0   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0
0.9922222222222222   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9929629629629629   0   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0
0.9931481481481481   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9938888888888889   0   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9955555555555555   0   0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.9957407407407407   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   X
0.997037037037037    0   X   0   0   0   0   0   0   X   0

                    31  32  33  34  35  
0.9885185185185185   0   0   0   0   0
0.9890740740740741   0   0   0   0   X
0.9894444444444445   0   0   0   X   0
0.9903703703703703   0   0   0   0   0
0.9922222222222222   0   0   X   0   0
0.9929629629629629   0   0   0   0   0
0.9931481481481481   0   X   0   0   0
0.9938888888888889   X   0   0   0   0
0.9955555555555555   0   0   0   0   0
0.9957407407407407   0   0   0   0   0
0.997037037037037    0   0   0   0   0
```

So, you can see on one glance which score was attributed to which model.